# Where to set smtp for Razor page authenication template?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to .net core and would like to use startup template from VS.
In VS2022, I started a new Razor page project with authenization type set to Individual Accounts.  The account registration process has email confirmation feature but I cannot receive the email.  How can I edit the default smtp setting so that I can receive confirmation email for my email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default SMTP setting in the project template. The default implementation of the `IEmailSender` interface does nothing. You need to implement your own version of the `IEmailSender` interface that uses MailKit or whatever SMTP library you prefer and register that with the service container.

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised MS make no explanation on the code for this.